# How can I register Handlebars helpers in a Micronaut application?

Tags: micronaut, handlebars.java

I am wondering where (or how) should I declare helpers for Handlebars in my Micronaut project?

I have tried following approach:

```java
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Micronaut.run(Application.class);
            Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
            handlebars.registerHelpers(HelperSource.class);
        }
    }
```

This had no effect. How can I register Handlebars helpers in a Micronaut application?

Comment: Finally, I replaced the HandlebarsViewsRenderer.class by a CustomHandlebarsViewsRenderer.class with the @Replaces annotation. Someone can tell me if this is "correct" please ?

Comment: Looks like that is what you would need to do. Please file an issue so this can be improved

Answer (score 3):

There is no configuration to register Handlebars helpers in current Micronaut 1.0 GA release. However, there is a simple workaround you can apply to overcome this limitation. To make helpers registration possible you have to access `io.micronaut.views.handlebars.HandlebarsViewsRenderer` class and its inner property `handlebars`. The good news is that this property has a `protected` scope - it means that we can create another bean in the same package in our source code and we can inject `HandlebarsViewsRenderer` and access `HandlebarsViewsRenderer.handlebars` field. Having an access to this field we can execute `handlebars.registerHelpers(...)` method.

You can simply follow these steps:

#### 1. Add Handlebars.java dependency

```groovy
compile "com.github.jknack:handlebars:4.1.0"
```

It is important to add it in the compile scope, because runtime scope won't allow you to access `HandlebarsViewsRenderer.handlebars` object.

#### 2. Create `io.micronaut.views.handlebars.HandlebarsCustomConfig` class

*src/main/java/io/micronaut/views/handlebars/HandlebarsCustomConfig.java*

```java
package io.micronaut.views.handlebars;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Date;

@Singleton
public final class HandlebarsCustomConfig {

    public HandlebarsCustomConfig(HandlebarsViewsRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.handlebars.registerHelpers(new HelperSource());
    }

    static public class HelperSource {
        public static String now() {
            return new Date().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this class I have created a simple `HelperSource` class that exposes a single helper called `{{now}}`.

#### 3. Load `HandlebarsCustomConfig` bean

```java
package com.github.wololock.micronaut;

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;
import io.micronaut.views.handlebars.HandlebarsCustomConfig;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = Micronaut.run(Application.class);
        ctx.getBean(HandlebarsCustomConfig.class);
    }
}
```

This step is crucial. We need to load the bean, otherwise Micronaut would not create an instance of it and our helpers registration would not take place.

#### 4. Create a view

*src/main/resources/views/home.hbs*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Now is {{now}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 5. Run application and see the results

[image]

#### `@Replaces` alternative

You can use Micronauts `@Replaces` annotation to replace `HandlebarsViewsRenderer` with a custom implementation.

```java
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces;
import io.micronaut.core.io.scan.ClassPathResourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.views.ViewsConfiguration;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Date;

@Singleton
@Replaces(HandlebarsViewsRenderer.class)
public final class CustomHandlebarsViewsRenderer extends HandlebarsViewsRenderer {

    public CustomHandlebarsViewsRenderer(ViewsConfiguration viewsConfiguration, 
                                  ClassPathResourceLoader resourceLoader, 
                                  HandlebarsViewsRendererConfiguration handlebarsViewsRendererConfiguration) {
        super(viewsConfiguration, resourceLoader, handlebarsViewsRendererConfiguration);

        this.handlebars.registerHelpers(new HelperSource());
    }

    static public class HelperSource {
        public static String now() {
            return new Date().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

It has a few advantages comparing to the previous solution:

1. You don't have to create it in the `io.micronaut.views.handlebars` package.
2. You don't have to get the bean in the `main` method to initialize it properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer !

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating some handlebars template from Firebase to Micronaut. Aside from registerHelpers, what about registerPartial(doesn't seem like they have a method on this)?